# Html Agility Pack Implementation

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am currently working on a C# program in Assembly where I am trying to implement Google Translate in my program. I am aware that I have to use HTMLAgilityPack in my program for it to work. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack) and [downloaded](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) the HTMLAgilityPack, however when he says

1) and build the HTMLAgilityPack solution.
2) In your application, add a reference to HTMLAgilityPack.dll in the HTMLAgilityPack\Debug (or Realease) \bin folder.

I do not know what he wants me to do. So far, I have downloaded and extracted the HTMLAgilityPack folder. In the folder, I have the files:
   Net20, Net40, Net40-client, Net45, sl3-wp, sl4, sl4-windowsphone71, sl5, winrt45
If anybody can elaborate on what procedures I need to do, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you download the [release binaries](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/downloads/get/437941) or the source code?  If you downloaded the binaries, look for a file called `HTMLAgilityPack.dll` and reference that in your solution.  No need to build anything.

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty new to C# and do not know how to reference in my solution. Can you clear this up for me? I am using Assembly if that is necessary.

Comment: In your project, find the folder called `References` and right click on it.  Then select `Add Reference`.  You can then select the *Browse* tab and find the DLL you want to reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you look at the API? There is a good example here...

http://forum.codecall.net/topic/64790-c-translator-using-google-api/

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio. There is in `Solution Explorer` folder named `Reference` -> right click -> add reference choose from hdd *.dll.

[image: VS adding reference]

After it you'll be able using methods from this Library.